# Smarty Regular Expression Match

Tags: regex, string, smarty, match

I Have a smarty variable, I want to know if it matches some string like

```
"<whatever>_thestring_<whatever>"
```

where `<whatever>` represents any sequence of characters (or no characters).

Is there some way to test against something like `*_thestring_*`?

Comment: it's very simple with this code: `{if $variable|regex_replace:"/^.*_thestring_.*$/":"_Find_SaLt_321!" === "_Find_SaLt_321!"}String matches!{/if}`

Comment: or this: `{if $variable|regex_replace:"/_thestring_/":"" !== $variable}String matches!{/if}`

Comment: Question shouldnt be closed.

Answer (score 9):

Using smarty to check if a string exists inside another string:

```
{assign "haystack1" "whatever_thestring_whatever"}
{assign "haystack2" "whatever_thestrings_whatever"}

Test haystack1 {if $haystack1|strstr:"_thestring_"}Found!{/if}<br />
Test haystack2 {if $haystack2|strstr:"_thestring_"}Found!{/if}<br /><br />
```

Output:

```
Test haystack1 Found!
Test haystack2
```

Or you could do a more complex search using Regex in smarty:

```
{assign "haystack1" "whatever_thestring_whatever"}
{assign "haystack2" "whatever_thestrings_whatever"}

{assign "check_haystack1" $haystack1|regex_replace:"/_thestring_/":" "}
{assign "check_haystack2" $haystack2|regex_replace:"/_thestring_/":" "}

Test haystack1  {if $check_haystack1 !== $haystack1}Found!{/if}<br />
Test haystack2  {if $check_haystack2 !== $haystack2}Found!{/if}<br />
```

Which has the output:

```
Test haystack1 Found!
Test haystack2
```

Comment: Or simply: `{if $variable|regex_replace:"/_thestring_/":"" !== $variable}Found!{/if}`

Comment: @Modder Thanks that looks like best option. Checked out smarties docs. Doesn't seem to have any other regex modifiers for some reason. No regex_match, oh well.