# Why can't I write if statement using prefix match in smarty?

Tags: php, regex, smarty

I want to write an if statement using prefix matching in smarty.
However, it becomes a syntax error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '!=' (T_IS_NOT_EQUAL)

Please teach me the correct way to write

```
<div>
    <p>text</p>
    {if $page_id === "video"
     || $page_id === "movie"
     || $page_id === $str|regex_replace:'/^live_/':'x' ne $str}
    }
     <p>additional text</p>
    {/if}
</div>
```

I want all ids starting from "live_" to be true.

live_a,live_b,live_c,live_d ... live_z

Comment: I found a solution which may help your case, you can take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18125918/smarty-regular-expression-match. Hope it help

Comment: Try replacing `|| $page_id === $str|regex_replace:'/^live_/':'x' ne $str}` with `|| $page_id === $str|regex_replace:'/^live_/':''}`

Answer (score 1):

**solved using "|strstr"**

```
<div>
    <p>text</p>
    {if $page_id === "video"
     || $page_id === "movie"
     || $page_id|strstr:"live_"
    }
     <p>additional text</p>
    {/if}
</div>
```